# Excel 2010 VBA: Copying rows, dynamically choosing them based on a value on a certain column

Tags: excel, vba

Just getting my feet wet with VBA for Excel. Looked around for similar issues and couldn't find anything exactly like this.

Pretty simple issue. I have some data and want to copy a section of the rows to another spot in the sheet. I don't think it'll let me post an image yet, so let's say it looks like this:

```
 Column A     Column B     Column C
 product1        1          #VALUE!
 product2        4            100
 product3        22            25
 product4        0             3
```

The rows I'd want to copy are ones where Column C is 5+. So, rows 3 and 4 in this case. The total number of rows should always be the same, if that helps.

I can do the copying and pasting in VBA, just wondering what the best way to select these rows would be. I tried a Do Loop with x being the column number, checking it was ">4", but I can't get it to work.

Thanks very much!

Comment: You don't typically find exactly what you're looking for :) have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12177125/212869

Comment: Thanks @NickSlash I suppose you're right. I'll look through that one and see if I can adopt it to my setup!

Comment: Post the code you have tried? That would help others so they can revise it to better suit your specific requirements.

Comment: @DavidZemens I think sous2817 got me on the right track. If I can't figure it out after messing with it for a bit, I'll post what I'm trying and ask for more help. Hopefully I can handle it from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a ton of ways to go about it.  Here's one:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim LR As Long

LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Range("A1:C1").Range("$A$1:$C$" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">4", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("A1:C" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Range("L1")
    Range("A1:C1").Range("$A$1:$C$" & LR).AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Adjust Destination range to suit.

Comment: Thanks @sous2817. That is definitely getting me on the right track. I don't want to take up ya'lls time with the fine tuning (the starting range is actually A18:Q18, below some other stuff, so you wouldn't be able to count all the rows and use that as the range), so I'll mess with it and learn that way :).

Thanks again!

Comment: depending on the structure of your sheet, there is a large handful of ways to find and define the expected range.  I just gave you one way.  Try googling something like VBA Excel Find Last Row for about 642,000 ways to go about it (granted, some will be more helpful than others).

Comment: So true. Many ways to do it, most of them I don't understand yet! I'll keep looking.

Comment: FYI, if anyone finds this in the future, I used a For/If statement (sorry the formatting is sloppy I thought I was doing it right but I guess not...):  

Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long  
endRow = 200  
pasteRowIndex = 16  
For r = 18 To endRow  
If Cells(r, Columns("BK").Column).Value > 4 Then  
Rows(r).Select  
Selection.Cut  
Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select  
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown  
pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1  
End If  
Next r