# Copy rows based on cell value and paste them into as new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've been searching the posts relating to using macro to copy rows and paste to a new sheet in excel but I can't seem to find the right code that matches my requirement. Here's a sample data to start off:
[image: Sample Data Sheet]

I have a DATA sheet containing 7 columns:

```
COLUMN A - Article #
COLUMN B - Description
COLUMN C - Lift
COLUMN E - Comp OH
COLUMN F - Requested
COLUMN G - Shipped
COLUMN H - SOS OH
```

I want to create a macro that will copy the contents of this sheet based on the COLUMN F - Requested and place them on a new sheet to be named REQUESTED.

The end result should be something like this:

[image: Sample of Results]

Comment: If the code that you developed after looking at all those other posts isn't working, please include it in your question and tell us what isn't working as you thought it would.  We can then help you to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vba macro to copy row from table if value in table meets condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177125/vba-macro-to-copy-row-from-table-if-value-in-table-meets-condition)

Comment: Just use a filter, and copy the visible cells.  Record a macro while you are doing that, if you must use VBA.

Answer (score 0):

This helps you
[image: **strong text**]

This is the sheet1 rough data
[image]
This is the Reuested Formule
[image]
This is the Reay layout
[image]
this is your Ansver After starting macro

You can use this macro to hide and unhide

```
Sub hide()
Sheets("Requested").Select
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    Set r = Range("F2:F10")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In r
    If Len(c.Text) = 0 Then
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub Unhide_All_Rows()
Sheets("Requested").Select

    On Error Resume Next
     'in case the sheet is protected
    ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```